# Hazelcast ignored cluster configuration

Tags: hazelcast

I have defined "static" hazelcast configuration:

```
@Bean
    public Config getHazelcastConfig() {
        final Config config = new Config();
        config.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "slf4j");
        final GroupConfig groupConfig = new GroupConfig();
        groupConfig.setName("projectName");
        groupConfig.setPassword("projectPassword");
        config.setGroupConfig(groupConfig);
        final NetworkConfig networkConfig = new NetworkConfig();
        final TcpIpConfig tcpIpConfig = new TcpIpConfig();
        final String[] members = "10.0.0.2".split(",");
        for (String member : members) {
            tcpIpConfig.addMember(member);
        }
        tcpIpConfig.setConnectionTimeoutSeconds(5);
        final JoinConfig joinConfig = networkConfig.getJoin();
        joinConfig.getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.setTcpIpConfig(tcpIpConfig);
        joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
        joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setConnectionTimeoutSeconds(5);
        config.setNetworkConfig(networkConfig);
        config.setInstanceName("projectInstanceName");
        return config;
    }
```

Where "10.0.0.2" is my localhost ip. I want only one instance of hazelcast added to my tcpIpConfig members. My friend is sitting in the same network and has IP with number "10.0.0.3". He is lazy to change password and group name from property file shared on git and is connecting to my cluster. Why he is able to connect to my cluster? How I can prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried using the SecurityConfig - http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/security.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesss, @Sachin. You are right. After adding

```
securityCfg.setEnabled(true);
```

to hazelcast configuration passwords and logins are checked.

Second problem I had with multiple hazelcast instances on localhost was related with hibernate. When using hazelcast as second level cache in hibernate there is created hazelcast member. It can be turned on/off by:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_native_client", "false");
```

or

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_native_client", "true");
```